# TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId stopped working on Azure function app (Windows)

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, timezone

We are facing an issue regarding time zones on Azure function apps deployed on Windows VMs, specifically with `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(dateTimeInUTC, timeZone)` method. We are trying to convert UTC `dateTime` to specific time zone.

When run on local Windows machine, provided time zone can be any of these: "Europe/Budapest", "Europe/Bratislava", "Central Europe Standard Time"... etc, but when deployed to function app on Azure only "Central Europe Standard Time" will be accepted. The rest will throw exception:

> System.TimeZoneNotFoundException: The time zone ID 'Europe/Budapest'
> was not found on the local computer.

We have this feature deployed for a few months and it was working as expected, but suddenly stopped and we noticed this exception.

Why is this happening? How come that both machines have Windows OS, but used method works differently on each? Is it possible that Microsoft changed something under the hood on the Azure infrastructure and we got this issue?

We are trying to run `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(dateTimeInUTC, timeZone)` method on Azure Function apps deployed on Windows VMs, but it does not work anymore.

Comment: Not sure if Azure changed anything, but using IANA time zone ids with Windows on .NET requires ICU on the Windows OS - which has been there since Windows 10 Creators Update (1703).  It also requires .NET 6 or newer. More on this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/international-components-for-unicode--icu-).  If you can't get it working, you can always use [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneConverter) to assist with the translation.

Answer (score 0):

**I could convert `UTC datetime` to specific time with IANA Timezone by following below steps:**

- Install **TimeZoneConverter** NuGet package in your function project.

**Updated Code:**

- Use below code in the `Function.cs`:

```cs
 public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
     [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
     ILogger log)
 {
     log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

     string name = req.Query["name"];

     DateTime currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
     string tz = TZConvert.IanaToWindows("Europe/Budapest");
     TimeZoneInfo tz1= TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(tz);
     log.LogInformation("Budhapest time now {0}",
                                       TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(currentTime, tz1)); 
     string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
     dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
     name = name ?? data?.name;

     string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
         ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
         : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

     return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
 }
```

**Local Response:**
[image]

- Deployed the function to Azure function app(premium).

**Portal Response:**

[image]

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't use `DateTime.Now` and `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id`, but rather `DateTime.UtcNow` and just `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`.  You can also simplify by getting a `TimeZoneInfo` object directly from `TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo`.  But regardless - this just is demonstrating using TimeZoneConverter as a workaround - it doesn't actually answer the question of why it's necessary in Azure Functions apps deployed on Windows - which should be able to perform the conversion directly without using TimeZoneConverter.